# Prevent multiple fetching for strict mode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call fetch just once when component loads and prevent subsequent fetches in React.StrictMode.

Is anything wrong with it?

```
let ignore = false;
useEffect(() => {
  if (ignore) return;

  fetchStuff().then(res => {
    setResult(res)
  })
  return () => { ignore = true }
}, [])
```

**Edit:**
I am actually influenced by the following code in react documents.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;

  async function startFetching() {
    const json = await fetchTodos(userId);
    if (!ignore) {
      setTodos(json);
    }
  }

  startFetching();

  return () => {
    ignore = true;
  };
}, [userId]);
```

https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data

But, i do not understand how it prevents, multiple loading, that ignore value does not change!?

Check following code, i simulate some API call result is saved to local storage. Second call by Strict Mode is ignored. Are there are any problems with it?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-useeffect-example-kaehjr?file=index.js,Comp.js,style.css

Comment: Which "strict mode" are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: In your snippet, it looks like `ignore` is a local variable, which means it will be `false` every time your component function runs (even without strict mode). You need to make `ignore` persistent, e.g. by using state. (But that won't address the strict-mode issue.)

Answer (score 0):

If you refer `strict mode` to `<React.StrictMode>`, your code does not prevent from calling twice. Because the `return` part runs when a component unmounts.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shared will only avoid setting state in an unmounted component, or ignore the first result in case of the double mounting caused by `StrictMode`, but it cannot prevent making 2 HTTP calls.

If you want to prevent multiple calls, you have to use a library like [TanStack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/overview), [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started) or [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview).